# Unix Df -k ouput in csv format

Tags: ssh

I’m trying to create a shell script to get the server stats of 100 servers and load the details into a table.Initially I’m creating a parameter file which has the list of all the servers, then I ‘m connecting these servers through ssh and run df –k.  ssh keys are already setup.
Issues I’m facing is that I’m not able to associate server name to the result, I want server name added as a column to the df –k output.
Also the output format cannot be loaded into a table as there is no delimiter or tab or space properly formatted to load. I have tried sed & various other options but no luck.

```
#!/bin/ksh
PARMFILE=/opt/sdw/scripts/db_scripts/server_stats.txt

value=$(<server_list1.txt)
echo "$value"
sourceservers=`grep =/opt/sdw/scripts/db_scripts/server_stats.txt |cut -d= -f2`

#Input array passed as parameter file to the script
set -A array_value $value
vLen=${#array_value[@]}
echo $vLen

for(( j=0; j<$vLen; j++))
do
#echo "${array_value[$j]}"
#ssh -q "${array_value[$j]}"; df -k
ssh -q "${array_value[$j]}" 'df -h' >> df.out
ssh -q "${array_value[$j]}" df -h | column -t  >> df1.out
ssh -q "${array_value[$j]}" df -k | tr -s " " | sed 's/ /, /g' | sed '1 s/, / /g' | column -t >> df3.out
 [[ ! $? = 0 ]] && echo Failure, errno $?, cannot connect to host "${array_value[$j]}" >> sshfailed.list
done
```

**Output**

Filesystem                                             Size  Used  Avail  Use%
Mounted                  on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvol3                                 1.5G  434M  923M   32%

**Desired output**

Filesystem,                                Size,       Used ,  Avail,    Use%,   Mounted  on, Servername
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvol3,      1.5G,     434M,  923M,   32%,      /                        br724

Answer (score 0):

put `"${array_value[$j]}"` in a variable like `$server` for better readability.

then in sed, do a substitution like `sed "s/Mounted on/Mounted on $server/g"`